# How to take data from a txt file and input it into a tuple. Python

Tags: python, list, file-io, input, tuples

This is all done in Python 3.3.2.

I have a txt file that I need to input into a tuple. The first line looks like this:

```
homework1 homework .1 homework2 homework2 homework2 .1 lab1 lab .2 exam_1 exam 1 lab2 lab .2
```

is there a way to create a tuple separating each piece of data by the white space?

This is one way I have tried.(I understand this is a list instead of a tuple)

```
Assignment_List=[]
Input=open('proj2_ex.txt','r')
a=Input.readline()
Assignment_List.append(a)
print(a)
print(Assignment_List)


['homework1 homework .1 homework2 homework2 homework2 .1 lab1 lab .2 exam_1 exam 1 lab2 lab .2 project_1 project 1 \n']
```

This returns all the data to the index [0] where i am trying to space it out so Assignment_List[0] will be homework1 Assignment_list[1] will be homework and Assignment_List[2] will be .1

Answer (score 0):

[`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is what you're looking for here:

```
with open('proj2_ex.txt') as f:
    parts = f.readline().split()
print(parts)
```

```
['homework1', 'homework', '.1', 'homework2', 'homework2', 'homework2', '.1', 'lab1', 'lab', '.2', 'exam_1', 'exam', '1', 'lab2', 'lab', '.2', 'project_1', 'project', '1']
```

Comment: How can i add each one as a seperate element into a tuple or list? I have attempted to do that with the split function and was not able to